# Porting over to C# from VB6, How to Open, Input, Close?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

```
    Dim strTestExample As String
    Private colTestExample As Collection

If(FileExists(strFullFile) Then
    Open strTestExample For Input As #intFILE
            Do While Not EOF(intTEST)
                Input #intFILE, strFirstName, strLastName, strFavColor, strAge
                Set objTestObject = New PracticeExample
                With objTestObject
                    .FirstName = strFirstName
                    .LastName = strLastName
                    .FavColor = strFavColor
                    .Age = strAge
                    colTestExample.Add objTestObject, .FirstName
                End With
            Loop
            Close #intFILE
End If
```

After numerous attempts to recreate this in C# its time that I consult the almighty powers. I have tried using `FileSystemObject` to open and write to the file. I am attempting to port this over to C#. I believe without checking i am working in .NET 4.0.

If you would like some further elaboration, just ask below. The contents are being input to a .txt file.

C# Attempt:

```
string Path;
string FullFile;
const string FileName = "People.txt";
TextStream TS;
FileSystemObject FSO = new FileSystemObject();

PracticeExample objTestObject = new PracticeExample();

Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
File = FileSystem.FreeFile();
FullFile = Path + "\"" + FileName;

            if (File.Exists(FullFile) == true)
            {
                FileSystem.FileOpen(File, strFirstName, strLastName, strFavColor, strAge);

                TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(File.ToString(), IOMode.ForWriting, true);

               FSO.


                objTestObject.FirstName = strFirstName;
                objTestObject.LastName = strLastName;
                objTestObject.FavColor = strFavColor;
                objTestObject.Age = strAge;
        HashTableRouteDefinitions.Add(objTestObject,objTestObject.FirstName); 

                FileSystem.FileClose(File);
            }
```

I have getters and setters on within PracticeExample.(WARNING, unfinished code.)

Comment: Just converting the code line by line (or *snippet at a time*) isnt going to result in a really good app.  Technology has changed since 1998. For instance rather than File I/O line by line, there are now serializers and various csv parsers.  Consider that changes to the basic app design are in order.

Comment: Yea I have been looking into completely reworking the application to remove the use of the .txt file and instead place everything in its own .config so that the application does not have to go out of its way to fetch the directory and sift through the .txt file.

Comment: I'd also recommend that if you are getting into .NET, MS published a set of 101 samples with VS 2003 showing basic functionality of many features of the .NET framework. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4856

Comment: You may need to prepare yourself (or The Boss) for the fact that after converting, The Best Thing to do may be to re-write (not rework) it once your translation is done.  No offense, but you dont seem to grok some of the basic capabilities of NET to make this work well the first time.  For instance rather than that FSO, there is an entire world of NET methods in `System.IO`, then there are collections, generics etc.  In effect use the translation as training in all things .NET to prepare you for the Real Re-Write.

Comment: Yea, i am new to C#. I have been developing in VB.Net and Java for the most part.

Comment: It is not about C# or VB.NET - FileSystemObject is a legacy approach which is suboptimal for VB.NET as well.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the overview. I will pursue an alternative direction with this functionality. Attempt, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: I've just come off a project that used a third party company to convert VB6 to C#.  They use an enhanced version of the VBUC that used to come with VS.  I'm not going to name them as I don't want to endorse their product.  All I'll say is you end up with C# that looks like VB6 and that isn't necessarily a good thing.  I'd always prefer a re-write to exploit new features and better OS compatibility but if you have a huge amount of code that you want to preserve it may be an option.

Comment: Its around like 5000 lines or so, not too bad.